# OpenCart - Создать обязательно поле

Tags: opencart

В файле confirm.tpl создал тестовое поле 
`<p><a href=""></a><input id="rules" type="checkbox" required>Я согласен с условиями!</p>`

Но при нажатии на кнопку "Завершить заказ" всё ровно required игнорируется и отправляется заказ.

**Весь код данной страницы:**

```
    <?php if (!isset($redirect)) { ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_name; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_model; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $column_quantity; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $column_price; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $column_total; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
          <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
          <br />
          &nbsp;<small> - <?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if($product['recurring']) { ?>
          <br />
          <span class="label label-info"><?php echo $text_recurring_item; ?></span> <small><?php echo $product['recurring']; ?></small>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"></td>
        <td class="text-right">1</td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</strong></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
    <p><a href=""></a><input id="rules" type="checkbox" required>Я согласен с условиями!</p>
</div>
<?php echo $payment; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
location = '<?php echo $redirect; ?>';
//--></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы это условие выполнялось и если не ставить галочку напротив "Я согласен с условиями" форма не отправлялась?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#agree').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
            }else{
                $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
                alert ('Ошибка: вы должны дать согласие на обработку персональных данных!');
            }
        })
    })
</script>

  </table>
    <div class="form-group required">
    <input id="agree" type="checkbox" placeholder="Условия" class="control-label" for="input-payment-rules" required> <?php echo $column_rules; ?>
</div>
```